# vue js import from node_modules

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I am new to vue js and currently trying to import any vue plugin/component into other sfc .vue files for usage.

Currently I am using VS code with `vue create project` cli setup and in my main `App.vue` file I am trying to import plugin after installation via npm.

I have came across this code at many places but not sure from where this has been imported. Also not sure how this path system works?

```
import SomePlugin from 'some-plugin';
```

My guess is that this comes inside node_modules folder after npm install cli part. Do we need to include full path of node_modules folder or vue-cli handles this automatically as full path looks weird.

```
import SomePlugin from '../node_modules/some-plugin';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Importing using only the package name will always look in the `node_modules` folder, regardless of whether the `node_modules` is in the current directory, the parent directory, or the global directory. Unless if the path is preceded by `./`, `../`, etc.